# Eclipse Subversion Plugin Subclipse shows an error

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I am using Eclipse Version: 3.3.2

I have imported a project which is on already on SVN repository. I just checked out in wwwroot and then imported into eclipse. Done some changes.  Then i was thinking to install subclipse. 
opened eclipse plugin manager installed Subclipse 1.2.4.
Then right clicked on project ->Team -> Share Project -> selected SVN. It shows an error :

> org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException:
>   Unsupported working copy format svn:
>   This client is too old to work with
>   working copy
>   'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\project'; please
>   get a newer Subversion client

Is there any problem with Subclipse? Is it effect SVN repository or my changes?
Should i proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several versions of svn, and therefore, several versions of subclipse (and of subversive). If you don't checkout your project with subclipse but with another svn client, you will possibly have problems if the versions differ. If you have made some changes, commit them with the client you svn coed your project with, and then

- either you install the matching subclipse (or subversive) version
- either you delete your project and check it out again, but with subclipse (using new Project> checkout from SVN)

Comment: thanks greg, so to use subclipse i should cheked out with subclipse not with other Subversion

Comment: You can use as many different svn client as you want, but they must have the same version number. The most recent version is SVN 1.6 format. On this page http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA, you can see which subclipse version corresponds to which svn client version. The best would be to have the same version as the one obtained when typing `svn --version` in your shell.